# Bootloader access over CANBUS on Nucleo-F446RE

Tags: embedded, stm32, stm32f4, nucleo, stm32f7

I am trying to flash code over CANBUS on Nucleo-F446. I am referring this application notes

https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00264321-can-protocol-used-in-the-stm32-bootloader-stmicroelectronics.pdf

So according to it in Boot mode the default baud rate of CAN is 125KBPS and we need to use PB5 and PB13 pin which are CAN2 pins.

For testing I tried to send CAN message with DLC=0 and STDID = 0x79 for which STM32 should return a ACK with same ID i.e. 0x79.
But I am not getting any response.

Comment: How have you connected PB5 and PB13 to the CAN bus?  Do you have a CAN shield (i.e., expansion board)?

Comment: I have CAN transceiver module to get CANH & CANL output.

Answer (score 0):

You must add a external clock to your Nucleo Board

> The system clock is derived from the embedded internal high-speed RC for USARTx and
> I2Cx bootloaders. This internal clock is also used for CAN and DFU (USB FS Device) but
> only for the selection phase. An external clock multiple of 1 MHz (between 4 and 26 MHz) is
> required for CAN and DFU bootloader execution after the selection phase.

[STM Bootloader Description](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00167594-stm32-microcontroller-system-memory-boot-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf)